# Select records in one table and specific matching records from the other

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables, two of which are relevant for this question. Users, Things, User_to_thing

**Users**

```
ID | Name  | Active
-------------------
1  | Joe   | 1
2  | Jack  | 1
3  | Tom   | 1
4  | Harry | 0
5  | Stan  | 1
6  | Bob   | 1
```

**User_to_thing**

```
Thing ID | User ID | Status
---------------------------
    3    |    1    |   1
    3    |    2    |   2
    3    |    5    |   1
    4    |    1    |   3
    4    |    2    |   2
```

I'm trying to create a query where I can select all the active users in the users table and have a column where I can see the status for "thing 3" from the User_to_thing table while also sorting results so that the nulls come at the end. So the result would be something like:

```
User ID | Status
----------------
   1    |   1
   2    |   2
   5    |   1
   3    |   NULL
   6    |   NULL
```

What I have so far for a query is the following:

```
SELECT u1.id, u1.name, user_to_thing.status
FROM users u1
LEFT JOIN user_to_thing ON u1.id = user_to_thing.user_id
WHERE u1.active = 1
OR user_to_thing.event_id = 62
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN user_to_thing.status = 1 THEN 1
WHEN user_to_thing.status = 2 THEN 2
ELSE 3 END)
```

What I'm getting as a result is the following:

```
User ID | Status | Thing ID
---------------------------
   1    |   1    |    3
   1    |   3    |    4
   2    |   2    |    3
   2    |   2    |    4
   5    |   1    |    3
   3    |  NULL  |   NULL
   6    |  NULL  |   NULL
```

I'm not sure how to limit it to just thing #3 while also getting a list of all active users. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the following should work for you, grouping to remove duplicates and ordering based on null

```
select u.Id as UserId, t.status 
from users u
left join User_to_thing t on t.UserID = u.id
where u.active = 1
group by u.Id, t.Status
order by case when status is null then 1 else 0 end, u.Id
```

Based on your revised data, you can amend slightly

```
select u.Id UserId, Min(t.status) Status
from users u
left join User_to_thing t on t.UserID=u.id
where u.active=1
group by u.Id
order by case when Min(t.status) is null then 1 else 0 end, u.Id
```

Comment: In your example, if user #1 has a status of 1 for thing 3 and a status of 5 for thing 4, what would the result be?

Comment: Well you can try it? You don't provide that as sample data but presumably it would return a row with each Status - you have not provided any clarification what it should do - however you can always add some aggregation, such as `max(t.status)`

Comment: I will edit my question to change the sample data, I can see how that wasn't ideal, sorry. This doesn't do what I'm looking for unfortunately. Ideally I want to get a list of all active users and their status for a particular "thing" from the user_to_thing table. If the record doesn't exist in the user_to_thing table, just show NULL.

Comment: Try and provide enough examples that incorporate your expected possibilities and it should be possible to tweak; it does tho provide the desired results you indicated.

Comment: Thanks Stu, I'm burned out from working on this for the past few hours but will rephrase the question better later when my brain is working again :) The specific status number for a user for the particular query is essentially the most important information in the query.